# How is the following code evaluated in C?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *p="hello";
    char *p1;
    p1=p;
    while(*p1!='\0')
        ++*p1++;

    printf("%s\t%s",p,p1);
}
```

What should the output be?
How is code evaluated?
Should the output be ifmmp or a runtime error?

Comment: How about you try it out by running the code?

Comment: have you run the code in a compiler ? did you try printing the results each time and doing more experiements ?

Answer (score 2):

You are invoking *undefined behavior*, as you modify *string literal* within `main`'s body:

```
char *p = "hello";
char *p1;

p1 = p;
while (*p1 != '\0')
    ++*p1++; // Undefined behavior
```

The following statement:

```
++*p1++;
```

is the same as:

```
++(*(p1++));
```

It can be written as two statements:

```
++(*p1);  // increase *p1 by one
p1++;     // increase p1 by one
```

If you want the output to be `ifmmp` (i.e. every letter is replaced by next one), then change:

```
char *p = "hello";
```

with:

```
char p[] = "hello";
```